# if else statement

Tags: regression

I am running rolling regressions, one with dvar (dvar is a dummy variable taking 0 and 1) the other without. Rolling regression moves with a 50 observation fixed samples taking one observation and discarding another at a time.
Here is the code, it is extracted from a for loop:

```
 if (any(dummy[(1+i-1):(1+i+wl-2),])==1){

         johcoint=ca.jo(Ydata[(1+i-1):(1+i+wl-2),1:5],type="trace",ecdet=c("const"),K=2,spec="transitory",dumvar=Ydata[(1+i-1):(1+i+wl-2),6]) # dummy variable is included
  } else{
         johcoint=ca.jo(Ydata[(1+i-1):(1+i+wl-2),1:5],type="trace",ecdet=c("const"),K=2,spec="transitory") # dummy variable is excluded
  }
```

This statement should run the first regression is any of the elements of 'dummy' is 1, otherwise, the second regression should be run.

I think there is a better way of coding this condition, would appreciate any hint.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go and see the default value of dumVar when you call the function without it, then you could do something like:

```
dumvar= if (any(dummy[(1+i-1):(1+i+wl-2),])==1) Ydata[(1+i-1):(1+i+wl-2),6] else 'default'
johcoint=ca.jo(Ydata[(1+i-1):(1+i+wl-2),1:5],type="trace",ecdet=c("const"),K=2,spec="transitory",dumvar)
```

where `default` designs the default value.